# How to create a temp table in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, temp-tables

I'm trying to use temp table to simplify my query. At the beginning I used WITH, which was not recognized if I'm not joining each table specifically. What's the best way to approach this query? what's wrong with this syntax?

[image: The data base]

For the account that purchased the most (in total over their lifetime as a customer) standard_qty paper, how many accounts still had more in total purchases?

```
create temp table t1 as (
  SELECT
    a.id as account_id,
    SUM(o.standard_qty) as all_std_qty
  FROM
    accounts a
    JOIN orders o ON (a.id = o.account_id)
  GROUP BY
    1
  order by
    2 desc
  limit
    1
)
create temp table t2 as (
  SELECT
    a.id as account_id,
    SUM(o.total) as total_purchases
  FROM
    accounts a
    JOIN orders o ON (a.id = o.account_id)
  GROUP BY
    1
)
create temp table t3 as (
  SELECT
    t1.account_id,
    t2.total_purchases as total_pur FROM
    t1
    JOIN t2 
    ON (t1.account_id = t2.account_id)
)

SELECT
  count(a.id) as count_ids
FROM
  accounts a
  JOIN orders o ON (a.id = o.account_id)
WHERE
  o.total > t3.total_pur
```

Comment: Different databases handle this differently...postgres will use the with syntax, while mysql version 8.0 and later will work but not earlier versions.  Youve tagged this as both mysql and postgres...mind specifying what db you are using?

Comment: Postgres. Can you please show how should I do it with Postgres?

Comment: Type 'postgres with clause' into google and follow the first result (should be postgressql: documentation).  Also referred to as cte or common table expressions

Comment: Terminate your statements with a semicolon (`;`).

Comment: Should work fine with `WITH`. More performant would be to put the "temporary tables" as subselects into the `FROM` clause.

Comment: I tried with WITH and it's not working, added it below..

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed a join with table t3 and you used it on where clause thats the problem ,can you please try with below query

```
WITH t1 as (
 SELECT
   a.id as account_id,
   SUM(o.standard_qty) as all_std_qty
 FROM
   accounts a
   JOIN orders o ON (a.id = o.account_id)
 GROUP BY
   1
 order by
   2 desc
 limit
   1
), t2 as (
 SELECT
   a.id as account_id,
   SUM(o.total) as total_purchases
 FROM
   accounts a
   JOIN orders o ON (a.id = o.account_id)
 GROUP BY
   1
), t3 as (
 SELECT
   t1.account_id,
   t2.total_purchases as total_pur FROM
   t1
   JOIN t2
   ON (t1.account_id = t2.account_id)
)
SELECT
 count(a.id) as count_ids
FROM
 accounts a
 JOIN orders o ON (a.id = o.account_id)
 inner join t3 on a.id=t3.account_id
WHERE
 o.total > t3.total_pur
```